# Machine learning - normalizing features with no theoretical maximum value

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

What approach is the best one to normalize / standardize features that have no theoretical maximum value ?

for example a trend like a stock value that has always been between 0-1000$ doesn't mean it couldn't go further up, so what is the correct approach?

i thought about training a model on a higher maximum (ex. 2000 ),but it doesn't feel right, because no data would be available for the 1000-2000 range, and i think this would introduce bias

Comment: I would consider something like a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) or some other [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), which maps all real numbers to a finite interval.

Comment: would you skip the feature normalization in the range 0-1 and leaving the data as is ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, no, I wouldn't. The basic sigmoid function maps all values to the interval (0,1), with 0 mapping to 0.5, and 1 maping to ~0.73. If you don't normalise the values from 0-1, then unless they are specially marked to indicate they are not normaised, they will effectively corrupt your normalised data.

Comment: i still don't get it: in a stock price example (it could be wathever, like a house price), there is no maximum , and the minimum is 0; applying a sigmoid to the data to normalize them would produce only the right side of the sigmoid curve; another doubt is that since the values tend to get higher, they tend to get accumulated closely to 1;  so the difference between S(1$) and S(2$) is a certain amount, but the difference between S(1200$) and S(1300$) would be almost 0 because they are both extremely close to 1

Comment: I'm not sure the default sigmoid function will be ideal, especially given the issue with precision, but any activation function will introduce these problems, with values above some arbitratrily large value being indistinguishable. However, I don't know of any other way to normalise effectively unbounded data, and given the right parameters, this method arguably behaves better at extremes than truncation.

Comment: Unless, you are needing to compare values directly. if this model needs for there to be a uniform distance function to compare points, it will fail to be useful on sigmoid-normalised data

Comment: one way i thought was to not consider the data directly, but the % difference between one value and the next one; this value is always capped between +/- 0-100 so it could be ideal, but i am not sure about this

Comment: I'd go for standardisation, as clearly the data does not have bounds nor is normally distributed. Your model won't be able to predict far into the future, so I would not worry about getting some extremes. If they happen in the short-term, it is very unlikely you would be able to predict them anyway, right? You don't have access to all the data AND crystal ball. You might want to add batch normalisation. Last but not least: sigmoids are evil.

Comment: The precentage difference is only capped if you take the percentage of the larger value. If it's sequential, then it's uncapped, e.g. 1 -> 10 is an increase of 900%

Comment: you are right; i was thinking that usually in a continuous trend rarely the increment is more than 100% , but it is theoretically possible. so what in these situations? train a model to approximate the range 100-115% of the maximum? (where +15% is a random number to be not too far from the 100 ) this doesn't feel very scientific..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: **use z-scores, maybe take log, maybe take inverse logit, maybe don't normalize at all.**

If you wish to normalize safely, use a monotonic mapping, e.g.:

To map `(0, inf)` into `(-inf, inf)`, you can use `y = log(x)`

To map `(-inf, inf)` into `(0, 1)`, you can use `y = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))` (inverse logit)

To map `(0, inf)` into `(0, 1)`, you can use `y = x / (1 + x)` (inverse logit after log)

If you don't care about bounds, use a linear mapping: `y=(x - m) / s`, where `m` is the mean of your feature, and `s` is its standard deviation. This is called standard scaling, or sometimes z-scoring.

The question you should have asked yourself: **why normalize at all?**. What are you going to do with your data? Use it as an input feature? Or use it as a target to predict?

For an input feature, **leaving it not-normalized is OK**, unless you do regularization on model coefficients (like Ridge or Lasso), which works best if all the coefficients are in the same scale (that is, after standard scaling).

For a target feature, leaving it non-normalized is sometimes also OK.

Additive models (like linear regression or gradient boosting) sometimes work better **with symmetric distributions**. Distributions of stock values (and money values in general) are often skewed to the right, so taking log makes them more convenient.

Finally, if you predict your feature with a neural net with sigmoid activation function, it is **inherently bounded**. In this case, you might wish the target to be bounded as well. To achieve this, you may use `x / (1 + x)` as a target: if `x` is always positive, this value will always be between 0 and 1, just like output of the neural net.